# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes

I'm trying to get values in array (files) and I want to save them in a directory so I'm using  `plt.imsave(os.path.join())` and I have a problem :

code : 

`for i in tab:
     plt.imsave(os.path.join(target_directory,str(i)), tab)`

I get this error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Someone has an idea please ? 
Thanks

Comment: In some part of your code you have a list (instead of numpy array I presume) and are trying to get its shape via `.shape`. But that doesn't work with a list.

Comment: what is `tab` ?? can you give us some moar code ??

Answer (score 0):

`tab` is likely not your image as you are iterating over it.

In fact, `tab` is likely a list, and Matplotlib's `imsave` is expecting it to be a numpy array (which has a `shape` attribute).

My guess is you do not intend to pass `tab` to `imsave` but something else.

Comment: We can imagine to convert my list to array maybe using `myarray = np.asarray(mylist)`

Comment: @Pythmania I don't get what you are saying. Simply converting `tab` to have the correct *type* does not solve the problem because this is an issue of *semantics*. The `imsave` function needs a 2D numpy array as input that can be interpreted as an image and currently it appears that your variable `tab` is not one.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (replace `tab` with `image`, or other variable that actually contains the image) :

```
for i in tab:
     plt.imsave(os.path.join(target_directory,str(i)), image)   # <-- here
```

Comment: if `i` is an image/2d numpy array, `str(i)` would probably not make sense. But in general that is where the error lies.

Comment: @lightalchemist hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code =)

Comment: @lenik I agree we need to see the rest of the code to know what is happening but either `i` is a numpy array or it is not. If it is, `str(i)` would not work. If `i` is not a numpy array, then we cannot pass it as the argument to `imsave`. Either case it will not work.

Comment: @lightalchemist don't really care if it works or not. my goal is to nudge the OP in the right direction =)

Comment: @lenik Alright then :). I agree with your above comment about the **images** and the intention.

Comment: In my tab I have a lot of filepaths just. Now I search to get each path and save each file in a directory :)

Comment: So when I print each elem in my tab I get this for example : `element : [ 'C:/Users/......../test/photo/chat/image1.tif']`and now when I want to save file I get the following error : `ValueError: Format "tif']" is not supported (supported formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff)`